# How to widen output window for text?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am want to print the output of a linear mixed model and the texts wraps.
Is there option that gets around this problem?

I have tried `option(width=1000)` and `tidy=TRUE`,`tidy.opts=list(width.cutoff=600)` to no avail.

EDIT: 
Here is a minimum reproducible example.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "NickHayden"
date: "5/8/2018"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
library(lmerTest)
library(lme4)
library(tidyverse)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
df <- sample_n(diamonds, size = 100)
df <- df %>% mutate(randoms = rep(c("A","B", "C"), length.out = 100))
mod <- lmer(price ~  factor(color) * factor(clarity) * factor(cut) + (1|randoms), data = df)
print(summary(mod))
```
````

Here the text should wrap around the window and lines may wrap under as well.

Comment: Could you please give a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Alrighty - I'll see if I can produce one. It'll be a bit.

Comment: I don't see any unnecessary wrapping when I try your example.  Can you describe what you think is a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An anternative is to export the output to a text file. The following link shows how to achieve this.

[Export R output to a file](https://www.r-bloggers.com/export-r-output-to-a-file/)

Example:

```
test <- c("asb", "asb", "asb", "abc")
out <- capture.output(summary(test))
cat("My title", out, file="example_output.txt", sep="\n", append=TRUE)
```